# Como fazer com que aplicativo seja bloqueado/desbloqueado na inicialização do Windows?

Tags: c#

Quero fazer um aplicativo que vai ter uma opção para chamar o **Regedit (Registro do Windows)** e o usuário poderá escolher se irá bloquear ou desbloquear para que o aplicativo seja inicializado com o Windows.

Já procurei em vários sites e até aqui mesmo no StackOverFlow mas não encontrei uma pergunta que realmente respondesse por completo minha dúvida, pois todos tinham códigos de fazer somente na máquina do usuário manualmente, mas eu quero que o usuário possa escolher dentro de uma opção se irá ativar ou não para que o aplicativo inicialize junto ou seja bloqueado ao iniciar o Windows.

Estou fazendo este aplicativo em C#,e gostaria de saber como criar isto.Se alguém puder me ajudar,irei ficar grato.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tenha em mente que tudo no C# é baseado em classes, então a primeira vista você deve imaginar que existe uma classe para isso.

A classe RegistryKey (Microsoft.Win32) serve exatamente para criar uma chave de registro como você deseja:

```
//Criando uma subchave nos registros, a string é o diretório padrão:
RegistryKey SeuApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
```

Agora o usuário pode usar dois métodos para criar ou deletar o valor do registro, fica a cargo de você a implementação:

```
//Adiciona o valor no registro para iniciação com sistema.
SeuApp.SetValue("NomeApresentacao", Application.ExecutablePath);
//Remove o valor do registro.
SeuApp.DeleteValue("NomeApresentacao");
```

Esse `NomeApresentacao` deve ser renomeado com o nome que você deseja que apareça.

Referência:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Obrigado amigo,testei seu código e fiz as devidas mudanças para o meu aplicativo e funcionou.